# Can't import WinPty in Mamba/Conda Environment

Tags: python, jupyter, conda, mamba, winpty

I'll try to outline what the issue I'm facing in this post:

## Issue

For some reason, the `winpty` module cannot be imported in the `base` mamba/conda environment on an AWS virtual machine I have running Windows Server 2016 running on an EC2 instance on AWS. Whenever I tried to import `winpty`, I got this `ImportError`:

```
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing winpty: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

However, when I installed mamba on my own local Windows machine (my Windows 10 laptop), `winpty` which was installed to the `base` mamba environment in my local machine can be imported with no issue.

I noticed this with other applications as well like `Spyder`. For some reason, on the Windows Server 2016 virtual machine Spyder crashed when it's loaded but on my local machine Spyder IDE 5.1.5 can be loaded in `base` mamba/conda environment with no issue whatsoever.

Below is the output of `conda info` which will tell you all the details about the conda/mamba `base` environment in my virtual machine:

```
  active environment : base
    active env location : C:\ProgramData\mambaforge
            shell level : 1
       user config file : C:\Users\<user_name>\.condarc
 populated config files : C:\ProgramData\mambaforge\.condarc
                          C:\Users\<user_name>\.condarc
          conda version : 4.10.3
    conda-build version : not installed
         python version : 3.9.7.final.0
       virtual packages : __win=0=0
                          __archspec=1=x86_64
       base environment : C:\ProgramData\mambaforge  (writable)
      conda av data dir : C:\ProgramData\mambaforge\etc\conda
  conda av metadata url : None
           channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
          package cache : C:\ProgramData\mambaforge\pkgs
                          C:\Users\<user_name>\.conda\pkgs
                          C:\Users\<user_name>\AppData\Local\conda\conda\pkgs
       envs directories : C:\ProgramData\mambaforge\envs
                          C:\Users\<user_name>\.conda\envs
                          C:\Users\<user_name>\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs
               platform : win-64
             user-agent : conda/4.10.3 requests/2.26.0 CPython/3.9.7 Windows/10 Windows/10.0.19043
          administrator : True
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False
```

## What have I Tried

I have tried:

- uninstalled mamba/reinstalled it
- create a new virtual environment called `test_mamba_env` and then in this new environment I:

  - ran `mamba install jupyterlab -c conda-forge` which will install jupyter lab along with winpty
  - tried to run `python` and then do `import winpty` and I got the same `ImportErro` like the one below:

  ```
  ImportError: DLL load failed while importing winpty: The specified procedure could not be found.
  ```

At this point I have no idea what caused the error in my virtual Windows Server 2016 machine.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!